# The sets $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k) = \Big\{ x \in (m, n) : x^2 = k^2 \pmod d\Big\}$ seem to have relationships with each other. What is their structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, sheaf-theory, integers, prime-gaps

For $m,n,k,d\in \Bbb{Z}, m\leq n$, define for interval of integers $(m,n)$:

$$
\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k) := \Big\{ x \in (m,n): x^2 = k^2 \pmod d\Big\}
$$

Then $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n, i)\cdot\mathcal{F}_d(m', n',j)  \subset \mathcal{F}_d(mm',nn', ij)$ where $\cdot$ is elementwise multiplication in $(\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)$ the monoid.

However if $c\mid d$ then there is inclusion $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k) \subset \mathcal{F}_c(m,n,k)$ since if the given modular congruence $x^2 = k^2 \pmod d$ is true, then it's also certainly true $\pmod c$.

This reminds me of adjoints in category theory, but I think some *other structure* is formed, something that hasn't been heavily studied & generalized to yet.

> **Question 1.** Can you figure out what structure is formed?  By that I mean do the two poset structures shown interact in any way?

---

**Application**.  The sums $$\theta(o,m,n,k) := \sum_{d \ \mid\ o\#} \mu(d)\cdot |\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k)|$$ seem to carry information about counting $2k$-gap prime pair averages sitting in the interval $(m,n)$.  In other words, depending on your careful choice of $m,n$, the count is either exact or at least very close to this count, i.e. only sometimes off by (maximally) some relatively small constant such as $1$.

---

By the above two properties we have that $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,i) \cdot \mathcal{F}_{d'}(m',n',j) \subset \mathcal{F}_{\gcd(d, d')}(mm',nn', ij)$.

> **Question 2.** Do the sets $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k)$ form a base for a  topology on $\Bbb{Z}$?

I can't figure out: if $x^2 = k^2 \pmod d,$ and $x^2 = k'^2 \pmod {d'}$, then does there exist $k''$ such that $x^2 = k''^2 \pmod {\text{lcm}(d,d')}$ or something?

Comment: I think a sheaf may be formed, but instead of the category of "open sets" $U\subset V$ it's the divisor poset category.  And instead of abelian group $\mathcal{F}(U)$ it's an abelian monoid $\mathcal{F}_d := \bigcup_{m,n,k} \mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k)$.

Comment: Thanks to whoever upvoted the post! :-o  I hope that means you will comment or make an answer :)

Comment: I think the answer to Question 2 is that yes, you simply take $x^2 \pmod {\text{lcm}(d,d')}$ and that is sufficient to have a ball within the intersection of two balls, containing $x$.  You could also take it $\pmod {dd'}$, but $\text{lcm}(d,d')$ is optimally the minimal such modulus so that the ball is contained in both of the given open balls.  And so the $\mathcal{F}_d(m,n,k)$ form a topological base, i.e. the set of unions of these sets form the open sets in a topology on $\Bbb{Z}$.  This is also probably a topological monoid (under $\Bbb{Z}$'s mult.), but I haven't proven that yet.